# Python IDE to work on remote servers

Tags: python, remote-access, sublime-text, visual-studio-code

For my work, I need to write and test some python code on several remote linux servers. I am looking for a user-friendly IDE on my local windows computer that can:

- "load" remote filesystems over ssh, so that I can edit these files locally
- quickly open terminals on those servers, so that I can run various commands

So far, I have tried:

- Pycharm: editing of remote files does not appear to be available in the community edition
- Visual Studio Code: I came close by using [SSH FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs) and [SSHExtension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kondratiev.sshextension), but that forced me to have two entries in the conf file for each server, which is quickly annoying

I also use Vim and SublimeText on a regular basis, but I'm looking for something a bit more user-friendly here.

Ideally, I would like the IDE to be able to rely on PuTTY, much like [SSH FS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kelvin.vscode-sshfs) does in visual studio code, since I already have sessions setup.

Any suggestions are welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [PyDev](http://www.pydev.org/) which is an excellent Python IDE plugin for [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

- Can do remote debugging with some [manual steps](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html)
- Free, Gratis & Open Source *watch out LiCipse isn't free*
- Remote terminal, explorer, etc., via [Target Management](https://www.eclipse.org/tm/)

Answer (score 1):

[WingIDE](http://wingware.com/) Professional Edition should meet your needs nicely (but not for Free after the 30 trial).

- Remote development over ssh (via PuTTY or OpenSSH) https://www.wingware.com/doc/proj/remote-hosts
- Also remote debugging via wingdbstub
- If you prefer to store the master copy of your code on your local system, you can do this as well by setting up file sharing to the remote host using Samba, NFS, or other method. However, you will still use the remote agent to access the files on the remote system, rather than opening them directly from local disk into the IDE.
- Licensing is per developer, allowing multiple installations on all of the supported OSes.
- Perpetual (with annual support) or Annual Licences *and some discounts available* https://wingware.com/store/purchase.
- There are even vi/vim keybindings.
- When working with a project that points to a remote host, the Tools menu includes an item Start Terminal that will start a new bash terminal.
- Lots of test support.
- Very nice to use

[image: How it works from wingware site]

*Wing is my personal preference - I do not have any other relationship with WingWare other than as a user & customer.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunatly I'm looking for something free for now, but I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: $180 / year or $245 for a permanent license.

Comment: @Neaffus - there is a free trail of the Pro edition, (2x15 days IIRC) so you could give it a try and then point to the productivity gains.